# Specify source file that defines function previously declared in a header file

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of C++ files that reference functions defined in a sub-directory inside `src/`. Is there a way to specify the cpp files inside the sub-directory via g++?

Here is the structure of the package:

```
# SeqLib
#   |----src
#   |-----|---Makevars 
#   |-----|---rcpp_hello_world.cpp
#   |-----|---SeqLib(a submodule)
#   |-----|------|---SeqLib 
#   |-----|------|---FermiAssembler.h
#   |-----|------|---src 
#   |-----|------|---|----FermiAssembler.cpp
```

************************* **EDIT** **************

When running `-I../src/SeqLib/`, I get an error `undefined symbol: _ZN6SeqLib14FermiAssemblerD1Ev`. Using c++filt, the symbol references the destructor declared in FermiAssembler.h but, defined in FermiAssembler.cpp

Comment: for the includes you have `-I` option. For the code, you have the linker...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I specify the includes with `-I` could I just reference FermiAssembler in rcpp_hello_world.cpp via #include "SeqLib/FermiAssembler.h" or "SeqLib/FermiAssembler.cpp"

Comment: don't include other `.cpp` files! and with your structure you don't need option if you pass the correct relative path in the include directive.

Comment: for some reason, the destructor defined in FermiAssembler.cpp isn't being found. I don't think g++ is able to find FermiAssembler.cpp at all.

Comment: as I said, you have to compile your .cpp files separately, then link them. undefined symbol means that at least the compilation worked. The link failed :)

Comment: ahh. So, I have to compile FermiAssembler.cpp first, then rcpp_hello_world.cpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass all the `.cpp` files to the compiler command. It's strongly discouraged to include `.cpp` files in other `.cpp` files.

The command line that is likely to work for you is:

```
g++ -ISeqLib -o my_executable rcpp_hello_world.cpp SeqLib/src/FermiAssembler.cpp
```

If you have a lot of files, it is advised to create a makefile script to avoid recompiling all the code every time.

if your `FermiAssembler` product contains `Makefile.am/in` files, it can build itself using a `configure` script which is probably here. The general idea is the:

```
cd SeqLib
./configure
make
```

If it's a library product, it builds as a `.a` or `.so` file. In that case, the command line becomes:

```
g++ -ISeqLib -o my_executable rcpp_hello_world.cpp SeqLib/bin/FermiAssembler.a
```

(I'm just gessing the path & name of the output library file)

To include .a files from there, just add their path. Not sure that `SeqLib/bin/*.a` would do it because lib dependencies don't follow alphabetical order. A very bruteforce thing that would work would be specifying *all* `.a` files twice (so inter-lib dependencies would work):

```
g++ -ISeqLib -o my_executable rcpp_hello_world.cpp SeqLib/bin/*.a SeqLib/bin/*.a
```

it would be better, though, to include only the required `.a` files, respecting the following order: first the ones depending on the following ones. The last library mustn't depend of any of the previous ones.

Comment: gotcha. Will try it out. There are about 10 cpp files but, interestingly the submodule has its own `Makefile.am` and `Makefile.in`. Is it possible to call them without running those 10 cpp files through g++. I'm guessing no because that'll just compile the code but, not make it referencable to rcpp_hello_world.cpp

Comment: what is `my_executable`? After running `./configure` and `make` a `bin/` folder was outputted with multiple `.a` files. I specified the path to them using `-L../src/SeqLib/bin/` Is that the correct way of specifying them?

Comment: `my_executable` is your executable (name it as you like). the `configure` command has worked! good. Now you can check my edit. You could also use `-L` to specify lib path then `-lname`  to reference `libname.a`.